# How to encode a JWT in Python?

Tags: python, jwt

In an attempt to create a JWT in Python I have written the following code.

```
# Header
header = str({"alg": "RS256"})
header_binary = header.encode()
header_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(header_binary)
print(header_base64)

# Claims set (Payload)
client_id="" 
username="" 
URL=""
exp_time=str(round(time.time())+300) 
claims = str({"iss": client_id,
      "sub": username,
      "aud": URL,
      "exp": exp_time})
claims_binary = claims.encode()
claims_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(claims_binary)
print(claims_base64)
```

I understand there is still more to do but I have the following problem. If I concatenate the two strings created above with a "." and put the resulting string in a JWT debugger it seems the claims set works perfectly but the same cannot be said for the header.

Please advise if this is the correct way to go about doing this and what my errors are.

Comment: If any answer has solved your question (also on your older questions) please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in the given answers, don't hesitate to ask by using the comment function under the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use third-party libraries? If so take a look at the [docs](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Install the `pyjwt` library using `pip`:

```
pip install pyjwt
```

Example usage:

```
import jwt

... # Define your payload variables

# Encode JWT
encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({"iss": client_id,
      "sub": username,
      "aud": URL,
      "exp": exp_time},
      'secret', algorithm='HS256')

# Decode JWT
decoded_jwt = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
```

Comment: This is a viable solution after installing module pyjwt using pip.  Thank you for the answer

Comment: @chrisb please mark my answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Python has a good module already created for this called, [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Try using that instead of following such a long process.

Also, it would allow you to use multiple algorithms to encode your data into, and other multiple features too.